# Make to show the Div when Hover the Text

Tags: javascript, tooltip, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating the div like below and I wanna make to show that Div when hover the text like tooltip.

```
<Div id="cont">

<table> .. <.table>

</div>


<Label> Show Me </label>
```

Comment: error in you /legend closing tag where do you want to close the legend on top or bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or else Try below.

```
<a class="popper" data-toggle="popover">Pop me</a>
<div class="popper-content hide">My third popover content goes here.</div>

<Script>
$('.popper').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    content: function () {
        return $(this).next('.popper-content').html();
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Below

```
<a href="#" rel="popover" data-popover-content="#myPopover">My Popover</a>

<div id="myPopover" class="hide">
    This is a popover list:
    <ul>
        <li>List item 1</li>
        <li>List item 2</li>
        <li>List item 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(function(){
    $('[rel="popover"]').popover({
        container: 'body',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            var clone = $($(this).data('popover-content')).clone(true).removeClass('hide');
            return clone;
        }
    }).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a tooltip is possible withot javascript, only HTML and CSS:

```css
[data-tooltip] {
  position: relative;
}

[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

[data-tooltip]:before {
  border-bottom: .6em solid #000;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  left: 20px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

[data-tooltip]:after {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: #ffffff;
  content: attr(tooltip);
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover:after,
[data-tooltip]:hover:before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href=# data-tooltip tooltip="This is simple tooltip message">hello world</a>
```